# Math operation between int and uint

Tags: solidity, contract-development

How is it possible to either convert uint to int or do simple math comparison operations?

Something like:

```
uint a;
uint b;
int c;


if (a - b < c) doSomething();
```

What I'm trying to do is to see if the subtraction of two integers are negative or not. however one of those values comes from msg.value so it should be uint, and I'm not sure if we do uint - uint the result could smaller than 0 to check it on if condition.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To convert one type to another, use `uint(x)` or `int(x)`. The rules are basically the same as in C, where the first bit of the uint becomes the sign.

For example:

```
if (int(a - b) < c) doSomething();
```

is likely what you want, as the numbers will be subtracted, then converted.

The `type(x)` syntax is used for all kinds of casting, such as truncating a number (`uint8(someUint)`), converting to and from odd types (`bytes32(someUint)`), or even casting a given address to a specific contract type (`someContract(someAddress)`).

Comment: Frankly, there is no such rule in **C**, so basically this is nothing like C. In C the behaviour of casting an unsigned into signed where the value wouldn't be representable, would be *undefined*.

Comment: *casting => conversion

Comment: I am having following error `TypeError: Type uint32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type int256.` how can I resolve it

Answer (score 9):

You can cast from `uint` to `int` by just doing `int(a-b)` but be careful. The `int` type in solidity uses the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system, so if you accidental cast a very large `uint` to an `int`, or a negative `int` to a `uint`, you may get unexpected results.

The values where this would happen are extremely large (numbers greater than 2^255, or about 10^77), so you don't usually need to worry, but remember that `uint(5-8)` is `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639933`

Answer (score 3):

When converting `var` from int to uint:

```
if(var < 0) {
    uint(-var);
}
else {
    uint(var);
}
```

When converting `var` from uint to int:

```
if(var >= uint(-1) {
    //can't cast - out of range of int max
}
else {
    int(var);
}
```