# How does Solidity/the EVM store a uint vs. an int?

Tags: solidity, evm

What's the difference, in terms of bit structure, between an int and a uint under the EVM?

For an example, if an int8's value, expressed in binary, was 00010011, what would the uint8 of that be? What would negative 00010011 look like?

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12397/how-to-correctly-multiply-signed-int-with-unsigned-int-and-store-the-result-in/12404#12404

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edition** (Thanks Tjaden):
when an `int` is negative it is represented using [two's complement system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) in which we get for an `int`: 1111 1111=−1(255 for `uint`) whereas 0000 0001=1 (1 for `uint`).

For example:

```
uint256 u=123456789;
```

is represented by `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000075bcd15 ( Big Endian)`

and `int v=-123456789;`
is represented by `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff8a432eb ( Big Endian )`

```
int w=123456789
```

is represented by :

```
"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000075bcd15"
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct. Solidity (and the signed EVM opcodes) expect signed integers to be in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) form. You can't just flip the highest bit and make the number negative

Comment: Elaborating on @TjadenHess, you could use the signextend opCode to do this for you.