# How to convert default two's complement representation to sign magnitude form?

Tags: solidity, evm, integers, bit-manipulation

According to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/21205/86303) the EVM by default uses [two's complement notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for handling signed integers. However for my application I would like to work with the [sign-magnitude representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method)
where the sign can either be 0 or 1 corresponding to + or - respectively and the remaining bits comprise the magnitude. For example, if a `int8` variable has a value of `+1` it would be represented in binary as `0000_0001` and if it has a value of `-1` it would `1000_0001` in sign-magnitude notation.

However since the EVM uses two's complement I first have to convert it into sign-magnitude representation before I can work with it. How exactly would I do this in a gas-efficient manner?

```
function twos_comp_to_sign_mag(int8) returns(int8);

// 255 in binary is 1111_1111 or -1 in two's complement notation
// 129 in binary is 1000_0001 or -1 in sign-magnitude notation
twos_comp_to_sign_mag(255) == 129
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked basically the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70816419/10261711) on StackOverflow but for python, below is my solidity adaptation using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70817147/10261711):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
contract TwosComplement {

    function twos_comp_to_sign_mag(int8 value) external pure returns(int8) {
        
        int8 mask = 2**7 - 1; // 0111_1111

        if (value < 0) {
            value = -(value & mask);
        }
        return (-1 & value) | (value & mask);        
    }
}
```

where the following holds true:

```
twos_comp_to_sign_mag(positiveInt) == positiveInt;
// e.g.: twos_comp(0) == 0

twos_comp_to_sign_mag(negativeInt) == -128 - negativeInt;
// ex1: twos_comp(-1) == -128 - (-1) = -128 + 1 = -127
// ex2: twos_comp(-127) == -128 - (-127) = -128 + 127 = -1
// ex3: twos_comp(-128) == -128 - (-128) = -128 + 128 = 0
```

To adjust this for larger integer types is really simple; change the variable types accordingly and update the mask, so for `int16` the `mask` will be `2**15 - 1`.

Comment: What does the & do over here? I used to think that they are only for logical AND operations for comparisons and such.

Comment: @Ishan `&` is a bitwise AND, you can read up on it, but in essence it compares each bit in the value to the corresponding bit in the mask and if both are 1 then the value at that bit in the result is 1 else it's 0