# Why doesn't the Yul instruction `div` work just like the high-level division operator?

Tags: solidity, assembly, yul

I noticed that the following Solidity functions are not equivalent:

```
function a(int256 x) pure returns (uint256 result) {
    assembly {
        result := div(sub(0, x), x) 
    }
}

function b(int256 x) pure returns (uint256 result) {
    result = -x / x;
}
```

If we pass 8 as an input, we get two different results back:

```
a: 14474011154664524427946373126085988481658748083205070504932198000989141204991
b: -1
```

What gives? I would have expected the results to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation has to do with the fact that Solidity (and the EVM) uses the [two's complement system](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/21200/24693) to store signed values.

In function `a`, `sub(0, x)` has this value (when `x` is 8):

```
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639928
```

This number is actually `-8` in two's complement. But `a` does not return `-1`, because the Yul instruction used is `div`, which cannot handle signed values.

To make the two functions equivalent, we could instead use the `sdiv` instruction:

```
function a(int256 x) pure returns (uint256 result) {
    assembly {
        result := sdiv(sub(0, x), x) 
    }
}
```

This will return `-1` for both `a` and `b`.